# Equivalent of the Shepp-Logan phantom for video denoising

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

The [Shepp-Logan phantom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepp%E2%80%93Logan_phantom) is a standard test image used in reconstruction algorithms as well as image denoising.

[image]

Does an equivalent image sequence exist for testing video denoising algorithms? I know that there are plenty of "natural" videos out there (one of two table tennis players springs to mind), but I'm looking for a more artificial test sequence.